# How do I upload an image and embed with base64 format in ckeditor5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using ckeditor 5 classic, this is what I have:

```
  ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#editor'), 
        {
            toolbar: ['imageUpload', .....],

            ckfinder: {
                uploadUrl: '/CKEditorUpload/UploadImage'
         }
    })
```

Then I created my own server side controller and I was able to get the data and saved the file on the server. I passed back the JSON and ckeditor 5 was able to insert the image successfully.

```
  return Json(new {uploaded="true", url="/uploads/xxxxx.jpeg"});
```

In JSON, successful respond looks like this:

```
{
  "uploaded": "true",
  "url": "/uploads/xxxxx.jpeg"
}
```

However, what I really want is to base64 encode the image and return it back to ckeditor 5 so that it will embed it:

```
 <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, xxxxxxxxx" />
```

Indeed,  I DID THAT successfully in ckeditor 4, but for ckeditor 5 there is no "window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction" anymore.  How can my server controller return the base64 data back to the client properly, so that Ckeditor 5 would be able to embed it? Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out myself... In C#, that's how I returned the encoded data in Controller back to client and it worked.

```
var data= "data:image/png;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";            
return Json(new { uploaded = "true", url = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(data ?? "") });
```

In other words, the JSON message would look like this. I didn't expect "url" would take base64. Anyways, it works. Hope this helps other people.

```
{
 "uploaded": "true",
 "url": "data:image/png;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: I think this is still going to the server and return back, do you know how to do it on the client side?

Comment: @AndySong this seems to let you keep it all on the client: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/base64-upload-adapter.html

Answer (score 0):

C#:

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpPostedFileWrapper arquivo = (HttpPostedFileWrapper)Request.Files[0];

            var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
            arquivo.SaveAs(tempFile);

            var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tempFile);

            var fileBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);

            return new JsonResult { Data = new { uploaded = "true", url = $"data:image/gif;base64,{fileBase64}" }, MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue };
        }
```

response:

```
{
 "uploaded": "true",
 "url": "data:image/png;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```